# How to subset by distinct rows in a data frame or matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, filter, dataframe, subset

Suppose I had the following matrix:

```
matrix(c(1,1,2,1,2,3,2,1,3,2,2,1),ncol=3)
```

Result:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    1    3    2
[3,]    2    2    2
[4,]    1    1    1
```

How can I filter/subset this matrix by whether or not each row has duplicate values? For example, in this case, I would only want to keep row 1 and row 2.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this: (I suspect will be faster than any `apply` approach)

```
 mat[ rowSums(mat == mat[,1])!=ncol(mat) , ]
# ---with your object---
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    1    3    2
```

Comment: Yep - 0.03 seconds for a 1M row, 4 col matrix over here. Impressive.

Comment: Vectorized functions like `rowSums` and `==` beat `apply/loops every time.

Comment: Just realised this returns a positive where there is for instance `c(1,2,1)` in a row.

Comment: This is great! I knew there was a faster way

Comment: @thelatemail: Yes. That was how it was intended. That's what I understood the request to be, but changing the test could make it return a different set of rows.

Comment: @BondedDust thanks! this approach works wonderfully.
I have modified it to this `mat[rowSums(mat == mat[,1])==1 & rowSums(mat == mat[,2])==1, ]` so that it gives me rows with all distinct values

Comment: After testing, this code only works for thin data sets. You would have to repeat the indexing ncol minus one times. I take my vote away! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
indx <- apply(m, 1, function(x) !any(duplicated(x)))
m[indx, ]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    2    3
#[2,]    1    3    2
```

This second one is just for fun. You can follow the logic to see why it works.

```
indx2 <- apply(m, 1, function(x) length(unique(x)) == length(x))
m[indx2,]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    2    3
#[2,]    1    3    2
```

Comment: the second approach is interesting, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

Here is my approach just a little bit shorter that use the `anyDuplicated` function, which should be faster.

```
mat[!apply(mat, 1, anyDuplicated), ]
[,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    1    3    2
```